# Transparent action bar and status bar

Tags: android

I want to create this interface of action bar and status bar in my application in android studio

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverlow. Unfortunately it's not Santa's wish list.

Comment: Please try to write some code on your own and SO will help you debug when you hit a wall

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods to do that

1. Create custom theme. You can do that by going to Tools->Android->Theme Editor and create your custom theme as per your requirement.
2. You change the `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` to `@android:color/transparent` in res->values->colors.xml.
3. Create a custom tool bar and set its background like this `android:setBackground="@android:color/transparent"` and change the `colorPrimarDark` to `@android:color/transparent` in colors.xml. But for this method you have to select a `noActionBar` theme like - `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`.

Comment: I have already tried this. But I am using an activity with drawer layout which is the mai problem i guess.

Comment: Even with drawer layout, you can use a custom toolbar and for that 3rd method will do the work

Comment: Ok thnx.. i will try that

Comment: Well it worked for me but now I am using a full screen background for my activity and it automatically hides my status bar, but I want the status bar to be shown always on the top.

Comment: are you using a FullScreen Theme?

Comment: Yes I am using full screen background

Comment: Change it with the theme I've given above. That will remove your toolbar but your upper header will remain intact.

Comment: Ok i'll try this

Answer (score 0):

Set Theme to Your Activity as below.
style.xml

```
<style name="my_style" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

</style>
```